# GCP - get full information about bucket

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I need to get the file information stored in Google Bucket. Information Like **Filesize, Storage Class, Last Modified, Type**. I searched for the google docs but it can be done by curl or console method. I need to get that information from the Python API like downloading the blob, uploading the blob to the bucket. Sample code or any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To [get the object metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#view) you can use the following code:

```
from google.cloud import storage

def object_metadata(bucket_name, blob_name):
    """Prints out a blob's metadata."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.get_blob(blob_name)

    print('Blob: {}'.format(blob.name))
    print('Bucket: {}'.format(blob.bucket.name))
    print('Storage class: {}'.format(blob.storage_class))
    print('ID: {}'.format(blob.id))
    print('Size: {} bytes'.format(blob.size))
    print('Updated: {}'.format(blob.updated))
    print('Generation: {}'.format(blob.generation))
    print('Metageneration: {}'.format(blob.metageneration))
    print('Etag: {}'.format(blob.etag))
    print('Owner: {}'.format(blob.owner))
    print('Component count: {}'.format(blob.component_count))
    print('Crc32c: {}'.format(blob.crc32c))
    print('md5_hash: {}'.format(blob.md5_hash))
    print('Cache-control: {}'.format(blob.cache_control))
    print('Content-type: {}'.format(blob.content_type))
    print('Content-disposition: {}'.format(blob.content_disposition))
    print('Content-encoding: {}'.format(blob.content_encoding))
    print('Content-language: {}'.format(blob.content_language))
    print('Metadata: {}'.format(blob.metadata))

object_metadata('bucketName', 'objectName')
```

Answer (score 5):

Using the [Cloud Storage client library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python), and checking at [the docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/buckets.html) for buckets, you can do this to get the Storage Class:

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('YOUR_BUCKET')
print(bucket.storage_class)
```

As for the size and last modified files (at least it's what I understood from your question), those belong to the files itself. You could iterate the list of blobs in your bucket and check that:

```
for blob in bucket.list_blobs():
    print(blob.size)
    print(blob.updated)
```